# Copy text in remote tmux/irrsi to local machine

Tags: ssh, tmux, irssi

I have my IRC setup done in the following way: my VPS runs `tmux`, which runs an instance of `irssi`. I connect to my VPS using `mosh`, which is SSH over UDP.

Now, when someone posts a link in an IRC channel, I cannot right click on the link, nor copy it to my local clipboard. Currently I am copying it through the copy mode builtin into `tmux` to a file in opened in `vim`, which I save and view outside of `tmux`, where I can copy it into my local clipboard and visit it.

How can I make it possible to directly click on the link inside `irssi` inside `tmux`? Or at least make it possible to select the text and copy it. Before someone is suggesting `xclip` or something, that would not be easily work as I would have to navigate inside `tmux` to the right section in my window.

To clarify:
I can right click on links in irssi when I SSH into my server. It does not work when I SSH into my server and open irssi inside tmux. But on my local machine, it can right click on links when I open irssi in tmux. I tried it inside `xfce4-terminal` and `gnome-terminal`, behavior is the same.

Comment: What Terminal are you using that won't let you select/copy ?  Or do you not have a local GUI ?

Comment: Assuming you want "clicking on a link" to open a web browser with a tab open to that link, where do you want the web browser to be running? Do you want it on your VPS or on the local machine? If the latter, what OS are you using? Do you want a graphical web browser (e.g. firefox, chrome) or a text based one?

Comment: I want my local instance of Firefox to open a link which is in a tmux window on my remote server. When I run irssi in a tmux pane on my local machine, this does works.

Answer (score 0):

Right click menu still does not work, but I can open links with CTRL + Left mouse button so I consider the issue fixed.